# How to create a full screen clustergram in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

How to create a full screen clustergram in MATLAB? I know that below code will generate a clustergram and will make it full screen afterwards, but I need it to be full screen from creation. How can I achieve that?

```
cgo = clustergram(patauc, 'Standardize', 'Row');
set(0,'ShowHiddenHandles','on');
set(gcf,'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to open the clustergram on the full screen, you just need to get the current screen size and put it into the `DefaultFigurePosition`. After this each figure will be maximized by default.

If you need the full screen mode only for your clustergram, you can get and save the previous `DefaultFigurePosition` to some variable and restore the setting just after showing the clustergram.

Here is the code:

```
clear;

%get and save the default size
defaultPosition = get(0,'DefaultFigurePosition');

%get the current screen size
screensize = get( groot, 'Screensize' );
%screensize = get(0, 'Screensize'); %for earlier Matlab versions (e.g. Matlab 2010)

%set default figure position to full screen
set(0, 'DefaultFigurePosition', screensize);

%work with the clustergram
load filteredyeastdata;
cgo = clustergram(yeastvalues(1:30,:),'Standardize','Row');

%restore the default size
set(0, 'DefaultFigurePosition', defaultPosition);
```

Comment: Thanks! For the ones who will use this code in MATLAB R2010b, you should get the screen size by `get(0, 'Screensize')`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to the BioInfomatics toolbox, so I'm not certain if clustergram specifically creates a new figure, or if it attempts to use the current figure. If it uses the current figure, you could try something like

```
f = figure('Visible', 'off');
set(f,'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
cgo = clustergram(patauc, 'Standardize', 'Row');
set(0,'ShowHiddenHandles','on');
set(f, 'Visible', 'on');
```

Comment: Thanks, but `clustergram` opens a new figure.

Comment: Yea, I wasn't sure about that, it seems a lot of the toolboxes have tools that insist on opening a new figure, instead of using the current figure.